# How to open a pdf file from Vim using the default pdf application?

Tags: pdf, vim

I want to open pdf files using their file links from Vim in the default pdf viewer application which is Preview on my osx.

There is `gf` normal command to [open](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor) a file link inside Vim. But pdf files should be opened in an external application.

Comment: `gx` is what you're looking for, but requires `netrw`.

Comment: @Ken Since netrw comes bundled with Vim, that is the right answer. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Spice I configured `netrw` to use specified external programs that are opened according to file extensions! Check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

As said by @Ken in the comments, you should use `gx`:

```
Certain files, such as html, gif, jpeg, (word/office) doc, etc, files, are
best seen with a special handler (ie. a tool provided with your computer).
Netrw allows one to invoke such special handlers by:

    * when Exploring, hit the "x" key
    * when editing, hit gx with the cursor atop the special filename
```

More information can be found in [`:help gx`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-gx).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:
[Vim - set custom editors to open `.md` & '.pdf' files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348543/vim-set-custom-editors-to-open-md-pdf-files/66353725#66353725)

What we need is to also enable opening PDF & MARKDOWN documents that have `#page=101` or `#chapter_example` prepended.