# Vim - set custom editors to open `.md` & '.pdf' files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

According to [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-gx) official guide it is possible to determine your own editors that are called per the filename suffix when in VIM we use command <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> *(while cursor is over a file name or URI)*.

This partially works for me. I used this block of code in the `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" make sure that viewer is selected according to the suffix.
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="-"

" functions for file extension '.md'.
function! NFH_md(filename)
    typora filename
endfunction

" functions for file extension '.pdf'.
function! NFH_pdf(filename)
    zathura filename
endfunction
```

Now I use Vim to open a source file e.g. `main.c` and navigate to these two line comments:

```
// EXAMPLE: ../../001--documentation/motorola--SREC_format.pdf
// EXAMPLE: ./markdown.md
```

If I hover with the cursor over the 1st one and press <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> I get this error:

```
Not an editor command:  zathura filename
```

If I hover with the cursor over the 2nd one and press <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> I get this error:

```
Not an editor command:  typora filename
```

So it looks like functions are executed according to a file suffix *(this is good)*, but why isnt a file opened? I am probably missing the knowledge on how to properly pass an argument to the funmctions? What should I do to sucessfuly open the files with editors `zathura` and `typora` *(both are installed on my system and can be run from the terminal)*?

---

After @phd suggestions I tried this:

```
" make sure that viewer is selected according to the suffix.
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="-"

" functions for file extension '.md'.
function! NFH_md(filename)
    :! typora filename
endfunction

" functions for file extension '.md'.
function! NFH_pdf(filename)
    :! zathura filename
endfunction
```

Which now opens the programs but it searches for the `filename` and can't find it. So function doesn't get the argument properly...

Errors are now:

```
error: Unknown file type: 'cannot open `/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/racunalnistvo/projects--pistam/2021-01-06--programmer_migration/002--sw/006/filename' (No such file or directory)'
```

and:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ziga/.../002--sw--006/filename
```

Also I read [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows) that `!` is not asynchronous and `!start` is a Windows only. I need Linux solution which is asynchronous.

Comment: "*I am probably missing the knowledge on how to properly pass an argument to the funmctions?*" No, you're missing the knowledge on how to properly run an external program.

Comment: @phd check my expanded question.

Comment: See `:help function-argument`.

Comment: I tried to (**A**) change `:! typora filename` to `    :! typora a:filename` but it does not work. I get error saying that `a:filename` file does not exist. Then I also tried (**B**) to change `function! NFH_md(...)` together with changing `:! typora filename` to `:! typora a:1` and it doesn't work. Instead I get error saying that `a:1` file does not exist. What else? Nothing seem to work. Vim keeps on reporting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
" make sure that viewer is selected according to the suffix.
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="-"

" functions for file extension '.md'.
function! NFH_md(f)
    execute '!typora' a:f
endfunction

" functions for file extension '.pdf'.
function! NFH_pdf(f)
    execute '!zathura' a:f
endfunction
```

If `execute` is not used then `a:f` is not expanded.

> **Note:**
>
> This is not asynchronous solution!

For an asynchronous solution we can install `vim` plugin [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) and change the above code to this:

```
" make sure that viewer is selected according to the suffix.
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="-"

" functions for file extension '.md'.
function! NFH_md(f)
    call asyncrun#run("", "cwd", "typora " . a:f)
endfunction

" functions for file extension '.pdf'.
function! NFH_pdf(f)
    call asyncrun#run("", "cwd" , "evince " . a:f)
endfunction

" functions for file extension '.html'.
function! NFH_html(f)
    call asyncrun#run("", "cwd", "firefox --new-window " . a:f)
endfunction
```

> **TODO:**
>
> With this there are very little annoying problems left. For example
> URI's ending in `.com`, `.org`, `gov`, `php`... aren't opened as it is
> virtually impossible to create a handler function for every possible
> top domain! There is another problem, because URI's to a PDF files
> that end with `#page=100` or `#some_chapter` aren't opened. Similar is
> with markdown source files where '#some_chapter' is ignored.
>
> Here is a quick reference works and what does not (copy in `vim`,
> hoover over the URI / file and press <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>):
>
> ```
> // ✔ EXAMPLE (g + x): ./markdown.md
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): ./markdown.md#test
> // ✔ EXAMPLE (g + x): ../../001--documentation/motorola--SREC_format.pdf
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): ../../001--documentation/stm32--boot_mode_and_bootloader.pdf#page=2
> // ✔ EXAMPLE (g + x): ../../001--documentation/C_--_HTML_documentation/en/index.html
> // ✔ EXAMPLE (g + x): https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): https://www.google.com
> // ✔ EXAMPLE (g + x): https://www.google.com/index.html
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GNOME
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): file:///home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/racunalnistvo/projects/2021-01-06--programmer_migration/001--documentation/stm32--usart_protocol_used_to_talk_with_bootloader.pdf
> // ✘ EXAMPLE (g + x): file:///home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/racunalnistvo/projects/2021-01-06--programmer_migration/001--documentation/stm32--usart_protocol_used_to_talk_with_bootloader.pdf#page=10
> ```
>
> If anyone finds a way to fix these problems or can write a vim plugin
> capable of opening these URIs it would be wonderful!